# How to set encoder for Spark dataset when importing csv or txt file

Tags: csv, apache-spark-mllib, apache-spark-dataset, implicits

I'm having an issue with this part of the Spark Mllib code from the docs (https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/ml-collaborative-filtering.html), using either csv or txt files:

```
val ratings = 
 spark.read.textFile("data/mllib/als/sample_movielens_ratings.txt")
  .map(parseRating)
  .toDF()
```

I get the following error:

Error:(31, 11) Unable to find encoder for type stored in a Dataset.  Primitive types (Int, String, etc) and Product types (case classes) are supported by importing spark.implicits._  Support for serializing other types will be added in future releases.

```
.map(parseRating)
      ^
```

I have also have the following at the start of my object:

```
val conf = new 
SparkConf().setMaster("local[*]").set("spark.executor.memory", "2g") 
val spark = 
SparkSession.builder.appName("Mlibreco").config(conf).getOrCreate()
import spark.implicits._
```

It seems that the read.textFile method needs an encoder. I have found a few articles on how to set the encoder. However, I don't know how to implement it when importing the csv or txt file.
Given that nothing about encoders is mentioned in the docs, there is also very likely that I have missed something obvious.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
val sparkSession: SparkSession = ***
import sparkSession.implicits._
val dataset = sparkSession.createDataset(dataList)
```

and see this link to find one of the predefined encoder. [Here](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/#org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession$implicits$)